# GoogleMap addMarker cannot have both setIcon and setTag?

Tags: google-maps, kotlin

```
private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap
        mMap.addMarker(options)
            .setIcon(vectorToBitmap(icon, Color.parseColor(color), this))
            .setTag(markerTag)
}
```

The code above won't work. But if I remove either `setIcon` or `setTag`, it won't display any error. But as above, it will display error `Unresolved reference: setTag`. If I remove the line `setIcon`, no error, `setTag` will work. If I put `setTag` above `setIcon`, it will display error `Unresolved reference: setIcon`

Did I jumbled up anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
       val markerMap =
                 mMap.addMarker(
                     MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Title")
                      .icon(vectorToBitmap(icon, Color.parseColor(color), this))
                    markerMap.tag = markerTag
```